# Command Line Interfaces - why?

Tags: ubuntu, server, digital-ocean

**Before we start this off, is this the right place to be asking questions regarding CLI? If not, let me know where to post and I'll move there. No doubt you lot will down vote this anyway**

So I've made a droplet running Ubuntu + LAMP on Digit Ocean and I'm getting to grips with the CLI.

But I'm **extremely failing** to see the point in using it. Why use a CLI today? 10 years ago, fair enough... but the GUI's of today are just as powerful for generalized tasks, in my opinion. Why use a CLI instead of a GUI? And I'm asking out of generalized needs, not a specific task that would be hard to do in a GUI. Just trying to FTP or view your files is hard enough after typing half of a books worth of characters into the command line.

It feels as if we're going backwards in technology when I have to use a CLI.

Comment: CLI is much more powerful and easier to use. A GUI always lacks features and it's a huge task to keep it up-to-date.

Comment: This seems to be more-or-less an opinion piece. Some are amazingly efficient at the command line and enjoy the low-level control it provides.

Comment: @juzzlin How so? I can't think of anything really worth using the CLI for over something like Windows

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Indeed, it is my opinion, but I'm trying to figure all this out, hence why I'm here.

Comment: I'm also unsure of how I'm supposed to have direct questions answered without you wanting to close the question because you don't like it

Comment: What kind of GUI are you expecting? A VNC like thing? That's a lot of bandwidth at a reasonable refresh rate. More than most of the world can manage on their home connections.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I'm talking like.... Why bother only having CLI/SSH access, just to type my life out into it when I could install windows and click 3 buttons to set up a server

Comment: That was somewhat my point. It's not my close vote but the vote is due to it being opinion-based. The goal here is to answer question objectively not subjectively. So, the way you prevent your question from being closed is by not asking those sorts of questions; or at least ask them a different way. I've seen many good questions get closed because the asker asks for an opinion when they could easily have asked for a "real" answer.

Comment: You've actually picked one of the places where CLI shines. Linux server administration is mostly done through configuration files and simple commands. A GUI would be a waste of time and resourses.

Comment: So then why do we have OS/GUI's is CLI is so much more powerful, more featureful and easier to use @juzzlin

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils My opinion is that there is no point in it. My question is exactly what it states in the post... 'why use a CLI instead of a GUI' - BECAUSE I'm failing to see the point in it.

Comment: Because a CLI isn't better for everything. You just picked one of the things it's better for, presumably because you are otherwise inexperienced with it.

Comment: @juzzlin Because CLI came out first? Name something I couldn't do within an Operating system, for example.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Correct, I am very inexperienced with it. I've managed to follow along and install things with it and get a live server going, SSH into and start creating websites. I just don't see the point in it, why not cPanel?

Comment: @Ashley Brown Ok, how do you do an interactive rebase with Git using a GUI? Which GUI do you use?

Comment: @juzzlin 'how do you do an interactive rebase with Git using a GUI?' I don't understand/or know what you mean by that. What GUI? Any, it doesn't matter, that's the point. click rather than type out lines is what I'm getting at

Comment: I have never understood people who think using CLI is too tedious, but still they have energy to write tons of words about CLI. Wtf? I bet this original question have more characters that what's needed to setup a server..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97229/discussion-between-ashley-brown-and-juzzlin).

Comment: To give an example of something you can't do with an OS GUI is compile a java program with some options and then increase the default heap size to - say - 4G. You can do it, but even in an IDE you're still typing out the things from the command line inn text boxes.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Actually, whenever I've needed to compile anything, I use a batch file that can be auto-generated. As for heap size... It's not really a correct comparison to use since you could say the same about using a search bar, or starting an application in windowed mode instead of full screen.

Comment: OK, but you asked for an example of something that can't be done. You may actually do it another way, but nonetheless the fact remains you can't do it directly with the basic OS GUI functionality. I also wouldn't put your window example and the heap size on the same level. Having a too small default heap size incurs performance lag that can't be remedied simply by pressing a GUI button as in re-sizing a window.

Comment: Update: So it's been some time since I initially wrote this question. Also, I've learned CLI a **LOT** more now and I'm pretty well versed in it, although, I still see it as *step backwards*.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons to use CLI is automation and pipe line.

Comment: And there is no way to do that in a GUI based system?

Comment: There is. but vendors for some reason do not do it usually.